# jquery - selecting an 'Option' in dynamically generated 'Select'

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

How do we select an 'Option' in 'Select' using jQuery?

```
$('#s_choice').selectedIndex = 1;//select 2nd item
```

Not working. JsFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/yesprasoon/pduX7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a refresh, also you can use either `prop` on jquery object or  access the DOM element property like this `$('#s_choice')[0].selectedIndex`

```
$('#s_choice').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
$('#s_choice').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Or just chain it through

```
$('#s_choice').prop('selectedIndex', 1).selectmenu('refresh').change();
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rR2Qk/)

Reason being, selectmenu is a JQM widget so after setting the property on the actual select element you would need to do a refresh on it to refresh the widget.

[Here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/forms/selects/methods.html) is the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. And, what do I need to do to get that selection-change alert message appear on start-up. It appears on manual change, but I am expecting it to appear when I change 'selectedIndex' as well.

Comment: @Prasoon You need to trigger ti manually since the selection is changed via js it wont get triggered `$('#s_choice').prop('selectedIndex', 1).selectmenu('refresh').change();`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#s_choice')[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

Or:

```
$('#s_choice').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
```

Or simply:

```
document.getElementById('s_choice').selectedIndex = 1;
```

The problem you have is that `selectedIndex` is a property of the DOM node, not the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

give your options different ids or classes then you can do `$('#s_choice').find('#option3').attr("checked", true)`

Answer (score 1):

[updated & fiddle added]

Try this, it will definitely change your selection and update the ui:

```
$('#s_choice').children(':eq(1)').attr('selected','selected').change();
```

place your index between the brackets in eq , ex : ..(':eq(0)')..

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/UBBUU/)

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, I've changed two things :

- Changed `$('#s_choice').selectedIndex = 1;` to `$('#s_choice').prop("selectedIndex", 1);`. For `selectedIndex` to work like the way you've made it to be, you need a DOM object, not a jQuery object.
- Changed the option where you choose where you want your scripts to be placed from `onLoad` to `no wrap - in <body>`. That means that your scripts will be placed in body. Scripts must always be placed in order for them to work. So no `refresh` is needed. for trivial changes such as setting the default value you needn't use a refresh method.

And Voila! It works :)

[Here's your updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/pduX7/10/)